# Blank screen when opening topics

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm not sure how long ago it started, but currently the app doesn't show me any topic I'm trying to open. Only a blank screen is visible. I tried logging in/logging out, reinstalling the app, and clearing the cache. Nothing has helped so far.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: HMD Global
- Device Model: TA-1053
- OS Version: 8.1.0 (00WW_5_58C)

Comment: By "topic", did you mean the Q&A page? Or..?

Comment: @SomewhatMemorableName, correct. Any Q&A page, i.e. this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c